# Write a typeof procedure in Scheme

Tags: scheme, typeof

Help me answer the following question appears in [Simply Scheme](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch6/true.html)

6.7  Write a procedure type-of that takes anything as its argument and returns one of the words word, sentence, number, or boolean:

```
> (type-of '(getting better))
  SENTENCE

> (type-of 'revolution)
  WORD

> (type-of (= 3 3))
  BOOLEAN
```

(Even though numbers are words, your procedure should return number if its argument is a number.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the form `cond` to check several conditions and execute an action accordingly. You can use the predicates `boolean?`, `number?`, `word?` and `sentence?`¹ to find out whether a value is a boolean, number, word or sentence respectively. That's basically all there is to it.

The only thing you need to consider is that the case for `number?` must come before the case for `word?` (because `word?` would also return true for numbers as the exercise helpfully points out).

---

¹ The first two are standard scheme, the latter two are defined in simply.scm, which comes with the book.

Comment: You're reading my mind. I am about to ask that question after read your reply. I'm so excited, since this is my first question on stackoverflow, and I got a immediate reply from someone who know the book! Thank you so much.